# How to view a Windows Recycle Bin files in Linux?

Tags: windows-7, fedora-17

I installed Windows 7 and Fedora Linux in different partitions and it's a different boot up. i want to view what are the files are in windows recycle bin via Fedora Linux, can any tell me the path for that.

Comment: I know that in Windows it's: `C:\$Recycle.Bin` and then there are generally sub-bins as links.  Not fully certain of how it looks from Linux since I don't have windows on my box to test with.

Answer (score 2):

The recyle bin folder is called $Recyle.bin. Each deleted file is represented  by a pair of files beginning $I and $R.